# How does magma_dgetri use multiple GPUs

Tags: gpu, lapack, blas, magma

I just installed magma and I noticed that some routines have `_mgpu` version while some not. For example for LU inverse, there are 4 functions:

```
magma_cgetri_gpu (magma_int_t n, magmaFloatComplex_ptr dA, magma_int_t ldda, magma_int_t *ipiv, magmaFloatComplex_ptr dwork, magma_int_t lwork, magma_int_t *info)
magma_dgetri_gpu (magma_int_t n, magmaDouble_ptr dA, magma_int_t ldda, magma_int_t *ipiv, magmaDouble_ptr dwork, magma_int_t lwork, magma_int_t *info)
magma_sgetri_gpu (magma_int_t n, magmaFloat_ptr dA, magma_int_t ldda, magma_int_t *ipiv, magmaFloat_ptr dwork, magma_int_t lwork, magma_int_t *info)
magma_zgetri_gpu (magma_int_t n, magmaDoubleComplex_ptr dA, magma_int_t ldda, magma_int_t *ipiv, magmaDoubleComplex_ptr dwork, magma_int_t lwork, magma_int_t *info)
```

There is no `_mgpu` function for LU inverse, and there is also no relevant input parameter in these gpu functions that indicating the number of GPUs to use. Dose this mean there functions without  '_mpu' suffix cannot use multiple GPUs? If the answer is no, how to do it?

Here is the link to the documentation:
http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/group__magma__getri.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since there is no `magma_int_t ngpu` argument for these functions, I assume that it's not possible to use multiple gpu to compute the inverse. But there is a potential solution within MAGMA: first call `magma_dgetrf_mgpu (magma_int_t ngpu, ...)` to compute the LU factorization, then call `magma_int_t magma_dtrsm_m  (magma_int_t   ngpu,...)` to compute `U^-1` using the identity matrix as the right hand side. Finally, call `magma_int_t magma_dtrsm_m  (magma_int_t   ngpu,...)` to solve `UA^-1=L-1`.

Comment: Before any attempt, make sure that your matrix is well-conditionned by calling LAPACK's `DGECON()`! Indeed, if the matrix is ill-conditionned, the accuracy will be lost and the computed inverse won't mean anything. See [How Accurate is inv(A)*b?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6035v1.pdf) for details: if the condition number is higher than 1e14, then even double precision will not be sufficient...

Comment: Thank you very much Francis! I'll try your method and see how is the performance.@francis